# What is the difference between weak var: test:UIView! and weak var test:UIView? in outlets?

Tags: swift, profiling, weak-references, iboutlet

So I'm trying to do some polishing and profiling on my code written in swift. I have a bunch of questions that are quite detailed and cannot easily find them by searching for the topics such as weak and strong referencing.

For example, I don't see XCode complaining for either of the lines below used for an outlet. I would appreciate if anyone can explain what is the difference if there is any, with respect to keeping weak references and memory management.

```
@IBOutlet weak var mapTab : MKMapView?
```

and

```
@IBOutlet weak var mapTab : MKMapView!
```

Is it just unwrapping or does it change the nature of the reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latter is an implicitly unwrapped optional. Whenever it's used, you can think of it as a force unwrap being implicitly done automatically for you. This of course will crash if the value being force unwrapped is `nil`.

The earlier is a regular optional, so you'll have to deal with unwrapping it yourself, explicitly. You can handle it with `guard let`, `if let`, `??`, etc. or you can choose to force unwrap it, explicitly, which will behave similar to the first case.

Comment: So I take it that it does not change anything on the nature of the reference to it, correct? weak is weak?

Comment: Yeah, that's an orthogonal concept. Your IBOutlets should be strong references. You'll only ever need weak to avoid strong reference cycles whenever you have subviews holding IBOutlets to their parents. However, that's a bad idea to do in the first place.

Comment: If my answer has satisfied your question, please rate it and accept it :)